# Android App tutorial not working

Tags: android, eclipse

i am new to android. when i try to compile helloworld program in ADT i get the following error:

> > [2013-04-12 13:36:40 - Hello] /var/www/html/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platform-tools/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

i used os:**centos 64 bit**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Same error was posted [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147400/problems-with-eclipse-and-android-sdk) it's a problem of libraries between your 64 bit system and the 32 bits of the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

download the ide from here:http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download,and chose 64-bit

Comment: i find the solution by installing zlib.i686